# Laravel 5 - clearing Flash session

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a page which uses tabs to display different forms.  To do this I do something like the following

```
<div id="cInfo" class="tab-pane in active fade">
    @if (count($someType) == 0)
        @include('forms.someType.someTypeCreate')
    @else
        @include('forms.someType.someTypeEdit')
    @endif
</div>
<div id="cAndC" class="tab-pane fade">
    @if (count($creative) == 0)
        @include('forms.creative.creativeCreate')
    @else
        @include('forms.creative.creativeEdit')
    @endif
</div>
```

So each of these tabs is its own independent form/Model, but they are essentially all on the same page, separated by tabs.  Now if I take the Controller for someType for instance, when it is created the controller sets the following

```
Session::flash('flash_message', 'Something updated');
Session::flash('flash_type', 'alert-success');
```

This works fine, however, if I then click on a new tab to display the creative form, this message is still displayed (because it is theoretically the same page).

Is there any way to clear the session messages when a new tab is clicked?

Thanks

Comment: Or, make it so, that your tabs are displayed through ajax, instead of page reloads. It's never ideal to have the same endpoint for different content since it is not linkable (i.e having a unique URL to a unique content page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display the success message in the tab or you can play with jquery

```
$(function()
{
    //if you click on a tab
    $('.tab-pane').click(function()
    {
        //hide the success message
        $('.alert-success').hide()
    })
```

})